# How is the parameter in a lambda function determined?

Tags: c#, parameters, lambda

In my example below, on the second statement of the function specifically, what is that 'n' parameter being passed into the lambda function. By the context of the code I assume that is pointing to the numbers list. But how can I know this definitively instead of having to guess from the context of the code.

```
//simple example of lambda expression.
public static void SimpleLambdExpression()
{
    List<int> numbers = new List<int>{1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
    var evens = numbers.FindAll(n => n % 2 == 0);
    var evens2 = numbers.FindAll((int n) => { return n % 2 == 0; });
    ObjectDumper.Write(evens);
    ObjectDumper.Write(evens2);
}
```

Comment: That entirely depends on whatever is calling the lambda.  You need to read the documentation or source code.

Comment: It represents the current item of the iteration.

Comment: I'd suggest that you use LINQ extension methods instead of `List<T>` methods so that you aren't tied to a specific implementation (`List<T>`). For the most part, there are direct analogs, e.g. `FindAll` is like `Where`.

Answer (score 5):

From the documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fh1w7y8z.aspx:

> The Predicate is a delegate to a method that returns true if the object passed to it
>   matches the conditions defined in the delegate. The elements of the
>   current List are individually passed to the Predicate delegate,
>   and the elements that match the conditions are saved in the returned
>   List.

Hence `n` is an element of `numbers`.

Answer (score 0):

You get that from the signature of `FindAll`:

```
public List<T> FindAll(
    Predicate<T> match
)
```

where `Predicate<T>` is

```
public delegate bool Predicate<in T>(
    T obj
)
```

So `FindAll` takes a function with a `T` input (in this case an `int`) and returns a `bool`.  The documentation for `FindAll` tells you that each item in the list is passed to the function.

Answer (score 0):

The `FindAll` extension method can be written this way (if it helps you to understand):

```
IEnumerable<int> FindAll(IEnumerable<int> source, Predicate<int> predicate)
{
    List<int> result = new List<int>();
    foreach (int item in source)
    {
        if (predicate(item))
        {
            result.Add(item);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

So the `n` variable in the lambda expression is the same as the `item`variable in this method.